# Graphical Issue on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04

I apologize in advance if this was already reported elsewhere, but I tried searching about my specific issue and have not found anything regarding it so far.

Basically, while using the official NVIDIA drivers (version 390.48 as of today) on an up to date install of Ubuntu 18.04, I experience the issue seen in this video I uploaded: https://vimeo.com/276640527.

Here are some other specs of my setup just in case they are relevant:

- Dell U3415W monitor
- NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1070
- DP to mini DP cable being
  used

It looks like the dock, or something else is crashing and restarting every 5 or so seconds.

This is  extremely annoying/frustrating, which is why I am hoping someone here will be able to point me in the right direction in figuring out the root cause of this.

I am fairly new to troubleshooting Ubuntu/Linux issues, so I am not sure what logs and such I should be looking at in order to figure this out.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you are using the nvidia drivers you have to file a bug report bnb with nvidia https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/522835/linux/if-you-have-a-problem-please-read-this-first/

Comment: It's gnome-shell that's restating. What's  causing gnome-shell to crash?, could be any one of dozens of reasons as g-s is a crashfest. See what the journal shows  `journalctl -r` and or check your syslog `gedit /var/log/syslog`

Comment: @Panther Would you recommend using something other than the NVIDIA drivers?

Comment: If the open source driver works , use it, or try sort rather than wayland

Comment: @Panther Alright, I switched back to the "Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau," rebooted, logged back into my machine with Xorg, and I am still experiencing the same issue. Wayland actually crashes my whole display every 5 seconds instead of just `gnome-shell`. I also noticed that every time I boot up my machine, I receive an notification that Ubuntu has experienced an internal error. When I look at more details, it looks like upower has/is crashing. I am also seeing a repeated line in `/var/log/syslog` stating that upower.service failed with result `core.dump.`

Comment: Pastebin the logs

Comment: @Panther I pasted the last minute or so: https://pastebin.com/hCEJjAMu. The lines I was referring to are repeated all throughout there.

Comment: Is anyone else able to assist me with this? I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.1 and I am experiencing the exact same issue.